# Where should UITableView dataSource be set, when loaded via StoryBoards?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, datasource

I am having trouble displaying data in my table.

Preamble:

- TableView placed on the storyboard
- TableView linked to a `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;`
- `.m` file contains both required methods and content to be displayed
- Controller conforms to `<UITableViewDataSource>`

I suspect i am not setting up the `dataSource` in the right place. Where in a `UIViewController` should it be set, when initialization happens from the StoryBoard? I placed it in the `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`, however DataSource was not set. Same goes for `init`.

```
[myTable setDataSource:self];
```

If the view is loaded with the help of storyboard (initialization does not happen as part of init method) .. where should table's dataSource be set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller's `-viewDidLoad` method would be a good option. That method is meant to perform any initialization that has to be deferred until the view is loaded.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'did not take.' Is the table's data source *not* set to your controller?

Comment: You are absolutely correct `-viewDidLoad` is the place to put this in. Is it an appropriate place for initializations like `data = [NSMutableArray new]`;